# Understanding the Group Structure

Tags: group-theory

A `Group` is an algebraic structure consisting of a set of elements together with an operation that combines any two elements to form a third element. The operation satisfies four conditions

1. `Closure`
2. `Associativity`
3. `Existence of Identity`
4. `Existence of Inverse`

Intuitively I understand the purpose of Closure and Associativity Property. But I'm not getting the intuition behind `Identity` and `Inverse`. Whats the purpose of having these elements in a group.

I searched everywhere and find only common definition which are straight forward. But nobody discuss why it's important. Can anybody explain it to me.

Comment: Semigroup(associative)$\rightarrow$Monoid(identity)$\rightarrow$Group(inverse)

Comment: Well, try to enrich your intuition by wondering why $0$ is such an important element of $\mathbb N$. Also why $\mathbb Z$ is such a welcome superset of $\mathbb N$. By working with groups you will gain intuition. It is not easy to just give it to you.

Comment: [Group (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) on Wikipedia gives plenty of examples. Did you read it before asking your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of an inverse (and  of a neutral element or identity with respect to which it is defined) is the fact that guarantees that we can solve an equation of the form: $a*x=b$ and find $x=a^{-1}b$.

This seems a good reason to deserve a special name ( and attention) to such a structure.

In other words: the existence of a neutral element $e$ and an inverse $a^{-1}$ make a group the simpler structure in which we can solve the equation:

$$
a*x=b \Rightarrow (a^{-1}*a)*x=a^{-1}*b \Rightarrow e*x=a^{-1}*b \Rightarrow x=a^{-1}*b
$$

Comment: I agree with your definition. But Can you explain the purpose of the Neutral element and Inverse elements with any example.

Comment: @Atinesh you're aware I did that?

Comment: I've added something :)

Comment: Thanks @Emilio Novati. I get the intuition now.

Answer (score 3):

Groups abstract symmetries of a set, that is, bijections $X \to X$ of a set $X$:

- Function composition is associative.
- Every bijection has an inverse, which is also a bijection.
- The identity map is a bijection.

Closure just allows us to consider sets of bijections that are smaller than the full group of all bijections $X \to X$.

All groups are groups of symmetries of a set: that's [Cayley's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

A huge motivation is the field $\Bbb R$ of real numbers, with which you are probably very familiar. So familiar, in fact, that I bet you *completely overlook* the importance of identities and inverses. Here, a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) is essentially two groups tied together via the distributive property.

In $\Bbb R$, we have addition and multiplication that get along so nicely that $a\cdot (b + c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c$. The real numbers form an additive group $(\Bbb R, +)$, while the nonzero real numbers form a multiplicative group $(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$.

In $\Bbb R$, we like inverses because they let us solve equations. For example, to solve $2x+3 = 9$, we might start by adding $-3$, the additive inverse of $3$, to both sides:

\begin{align*}2x + \underbrace{3 + (-3)}_\text{inverses} &= 9 + (-3) \\
2x + 0 &= 6.
\end{align*}

We normally suppress writing the $+0$ part, but it's important to realize that additive inverses add up to the additive identity, $0$. Now the property of the additive identity says that adding $0$ doesn't actually change anything, and that our equation is in fact equivalent to $2x = 6$.

Now we know what $2x$ is, but we really want to know what $x$ is. We need to "undo" multiplying $x$ by $2$. We'll multiply by the multiplicative inverse of $2$ then, $2^{-1} = \frac12$:

\begin{align*}
\underbrace{2^{-1}\cdot 2}_\text{inverses}x &= 2^{-1}\cdot 6 \\
1x &= 3
\end{align*}

where we know, of course, that $1x = x$, since multiplying by $1$ doesn't change anything (just like adding $0$ doesn't either). Another way to phrase this is to say that $1$ is the multiplicative *identity*.

---

In general, we like invertible processes. Math is full of operations that *change* things, and invertible operations - those with an inverse in the group-theoretic sense - are operations that can be undone reliably.

But this brings up the question: Given our vague description of invertible operations and "undoing" things, what does it mean to say that an operation is invertible; how do we know if we really have "undone" a certain operation? This is formalized by having identity elements/operations, those group elements that truly "do nothing" (like multiplying by $1$, or adding $0$). We can easily characterize operations that are inverses as those that, when performed in succession, amount to the identity, or "do nothing" operation.

Answer (score 1):

A group describes the symmetries of some other mathematical object. Consider the square:
[image: square]

**Associativity:** If I rotate the square 90$^{\circ}$ clockwise twice ($RR)$ and then flip it ($F$), I should get the same thing as rotating it 90$^{\circ}$ once, and then performing the second rotation and flip afterwards. That is, $(RR)F=R(RF)$.

**Closure:** Applying any two symmetries to the square still produces the square (with a potentially different vertex labeling) again. For example applying $RRF$ gives another symmetry of the square above, but the vertices are now labeled (going clockwise) $4,\ 3,\ 2,\ 1$.

**Inverses:** Simply put, if I apply a symmetry to the square, I should be able to undo that operation to get back to what we had. Following the example above, in order to undo $RRF$ above, we need to flip it again, and then rotate it twice. This is because flipping it across the axis twice does not change the square, and rotating it 90$^{\circ}$ 4 times also doesn't change the labeling of the vertices. So: $(RRF)(FRR) = R^2F^2R^2 = R^4 = I$. This brings us to:

**Identity:** not changing the vertices of the above is the simplest way to procude a symmetry.

The notion of a group encodes all of these concepts into it's structure.

Answer (score 0):

[This page might be worth a read](http://maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Group)

Think of a group exactly how that page describes, a set $G$ and a function $f:G\times G\rightarrow G$ such that
**identity**) There exists an $e\in G$ such that for all $g\in G$ we have $f(e,g)=f(g,e)=g$
**inverse**) Forall $x$ in $G$ there exists a $y\in G$ such that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)=e$
(and the other 2 properties, which you seem to get)

Only now rather than $f$ we have say, $+$, so $a+b:=f(a,b)$, or multiplicative, $xy=f(x,y)$ say. That's all that is going on.

A group is simply a function and a set with those 4 properties.

The integers, $\{\ldots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $+$ are an example of a group, $0$ is the identity, as $x+0=0+x=x$ for all $x$. The inverse (which is unique, as is the identity) is $-x$, for example $7+(-7)=0$.

Hope this helps.

This structure ensures you have an "element that does nothing (the identity)" and the inverse ensures "you can go back" if you will, this structure occurs in A LOT of places. One not obvious one is in topology with the fundamental group. I leave you to look that up.

Gist:
[Fundamental group](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Fundamental_group) - we say two loops (literally loops on a surface say) are homotopic if you can move (deform) one into the other. Two loops are equiv. if they are homotopic. The fundamental group is a group on these homotopic classes! I don't have time to explain it in greater detail. There are far more interesting groups than just number theory would suggest!

Comment: The link you gave isn't working properly. Can you refer me any other text.

Comment: @Atinesh any book with "abstract algebra" in the title, and the link works for me (both do)

Comment: @Atinesh is there a problem?

Comment: Doesn't deserve -1

Comment: Should not be -1 unfair.